# Python: Dictionary update using variables adds new keys but replaces old values with the new one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to store information in dictionary that I want to access later. I am doing it dynamically using variables, where "badgeID" is a global counter that I am using as key and value is an array/list that I get from the user.

[image: Here is the screen shot]

The problem that when I try to add more than one K:V to the dictionary, it adds a key but replaces all the previously stored values(in this case it is an array/list) with the newest one. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code *as formatted text* not as an image.

Comment: NO. Put that *in the original question as formatted text*... do you really expect people to read that in a comment???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Check the post.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem that when I try to add more than one K:V to the
>   dictionary, it adds a key but replaces all the previously stored
>   values(in this case it is an array/list) with the newest one.

The technique to solve this problem is that every key, *badgeNum*, news a list of values rather than a single value.

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict.setdefault(1234, []).append('first 1234')
>>> mydict.setdefault(5678, []).append('first 5678')
>>> mydict.setdefault(1234, []).append('second 1234')
>>> mydict.setdefault(5678, []).append('second 5678')
>>> mydict
{1234: ['first 1234', 'second 1234'], 5678: ['first 5678', 'second 5678']}
```

Another approach is to use [*collections.defaultdict()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which takes a little more effort to set-up but makes it simpler (and a bit faster) to add new values:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(list)
>>> mydict[1234].append('first 1234')
>>> mydict[5678].append('first 5678')
>>> mydict[1234].append('second 1234')
>>> mydict[5678].append('second 5678')
>>> mydict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1234: ['first 1234', 'second 1234'], 5678: ['first 5678', 'second 5678']})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't get it. I'm relatively new to python and I have been reading the documentation but couldn't figure it out. So you mean if use setdefault() it'll help? Because I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @RahulJoshi Sorry about that, I posted the wrong snippet.  It is fixed now.  The technique is to use *dict.setdefault* or *collections.defaultdict* to create new empty lists for previously unseen keys and to the append new entries to that list.